# Adjusting header in CSV file

Tags: php, csv, logging, header

I have a log routine on my PHP website, that puts data on daily CSV files. Here's the code:

```
public function generateLogPMWeb($action){
    session_start('usuario');

    $head_data = "HOSPEDE_CODIGO" . ";" . "RESERVA_CODIGO" . ";" . "HOSPEDE_NOME" . ";" . "HOSPEDE_SOBRENOME" . ";" . "HOSPEDE_EMAIL" . ";" . "RESERVA_DESCRICAOSISTEMA" . ";" . "RESERVA_CODIGOLOCALIZADOR" . ";" . "RESERVA_CODIGOHOTEL" . ";" . "RESERVA_DATARESERVA" . ";" . "RESERVA_DATACHECKIN" . ";" . "RESERVA_DATACHECKOUT" . ";" . "ACAO" . ";\n";
    file_put_contents(Config::retorna("document_root", "root").'/logPMWeb/logPMWeb_'.date("Ymd").'.csv', $head_data, FILE_APPEND); // MUDAR AQUI

    $logPMWeb  = $_SESSION['usuario']['id'] . ";" . date('YmdHis') . "_" . $_POST['idHotel'] . "_" . $_SESSION['usuario']['id'] . ";" . $_SESSION['usuario']['nome'] . ";" . $_SESSION['usuario']['sobrenome'] . ";" . $_SESSION['usuario']['email'] . ";" . "IC"
            . ";" . date('YmdHis') . "_" . $_POST['idHotel'] . "_" . $_SESSION['usuario']['id'] . ";" . $_POST['idHotel'] . ";" . date('Y-m-d H:i:s') . ";" . $_SESSION['buscaReserva']['dataInicio'] . ";" . $_SESSION['buscaReserva']['dataFim']
            . ";" . preg_replace('/^\s+|\n|\r|\s+$/m', '', $action) . ";\n";
    //Save string to log, use FILE_APPEND to append.
    file_put_contents(Config::retorna("document_root", "root").'/logPMWeb/logPMWeb_'.date("Ymd").'.csv', $logPMWeb, FILE_APPEND);
}
```

However I'm getting repeated header lines on my CSV files. I need to have the header only on the first line of the file.

What's the best thing to do?

Answer (score 0):

Use file_exists like below...  http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php

```
public function generateLogPMWeb($action){
    session_start('usuario');

    $logfile = Config::retorna("document_root", "root").'/logPMWeb/logPMWeb_'.date("Ymd").'.csv'

    $head_data = "HOSPEDE_CODIGO" . ";" . "RESERVA_CODIGO" . ";" . "HOSPEDE_NOME" . ";" . "HOSPEDE_SOBRENOME" . ";" . "HOSPEDE_EMAIL" . ";" . "RESERVA_DESCRICAOSISTEMA" . ";" . "RESERVA_CODIGOLOCALIZADOR" . ";" . "RESERVA_CODIGOHOTEL" . ";" . "RESERVA_DATARESERVA" . ";" . "RESERVA_DATACHECKIN" . ";" . "RESERVA_DATACHECKOUT" . ";" . "ACAO" . ";\n";
    if (!file_exists($logfile)) {
       file_put_contents($logfile, $head_data, FILE_APPEND); // MUDAR AQUI
    }

    $logPMWeb  = $_SESSION['usuario']['id'] . ";" . date('YmdHis') . "_" . $_POST['idHotel'] . "_" . $_SESSION['usuario']['id'] . ";" . $_SESSION['usuario']['nome'] . ";" . $_SESSION['usuario']['sobrenome'] . ";" . $_SESSION['usuario']['email'] . ";" . "IC"
            . ";" . date('YmdHis') . "_" . $_POST['idHotel'] . "_" . $_SESSION['usuario']['id'] . ";" . $_POST['idHotel'] . ";" . date('Y-m-d H:i:s') . ";" . $_SESSION['buscaReserva']['dataInicio'] . ";" . $_SESSION['buscaReserva']['dataFim']
            . ";" . preg_replace('/^\s+|\n|\r|\s+$/m', '', $action) . ";\n";
    //Save string to log, use FILE_APPEND to append.
    file_put_contents($logfile, $logPMWeb, FILE_APPEND);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked!!! Only the first line i had to change the position of the exclamation point. Like this: if (!file_exists($logfile)) {